# Some Pytest fixture attributes don't get reset after each test

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a Python class like this:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, r=range(10)):
        self.r = r
    def bar(self):
        # code
    def hop(self):
        # code
```

and I want to test it like this:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def foo():
    return Foo()

def test_bar(foo):
    # run tests
    foo.r = range(20)
    # run more tests

def test_hop(foo):
    # run tests
```

I want the value of `foo.r` in `test_hop()` to be `range(10)`, but instead it's `range(20)`. Why is the value not getting reset?

I tried re-defining the fixture decorator as `@pytest.fixture(scope='function')` (this is the default value, but I wanted to make sure that the fixture was getting 'torn down' at the end of each test). It made no difference to the result.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `range`s in Python are mutable. Thus, any changes made inside a test function will persist in subsequent test functions. Had the argument `r` to `__init__()` been something immutable, the fixture would have reset between tests as expected.

One way to get around this is to define `r` as a tuple containing the limits of the range (tuples are immutable). Then, create the actual `range` variable inside `__init__()`, i.e.:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, r=tuple(0,10)):
        self.r = range(r[0],r[1])
    def bar(self):
        # code
    def hop(self):
        # code
```

Now, the value of `foo.r` in `test_hop()` will be `range(10)`.